# How can I take multiple trades when condition is satisfied?

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I have made an Expert Advisor (please see code below). It only takes one trade at a time though. There are several instances that the conditions for trade entry are met more than once but only one trade is taken at a time. How can I make it a new trade whenever an entry condition is met and exit all trades when an exit condition is met?

```
extern int MagicNumber=10001;
extern double Lots =0.01;
double StopLoss=0;
double TakeProfit=50;
int TrailingStop=0;
int Slippage=3;

int start()
{
  double MyPoint=Point;
  if(Digits==3 || Digits==5) MyPoint=Point*10;

  double TheStopLoss=0;
  double TheTakeProfit=0;
  if( TotalOrdersCount()==0 ) 
  {
     int result=0;
     if(
     (iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_SIGNAL,0)<iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_MAIN,0))&&
 (iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,1)<iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,0)) 
     ) // Here is your open buy rule
     {
        result=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,Lots,Ask,Slippage,0,0,"Test",MagicNumber,0,Blue);
    Alert("BUY OPENED");
    //if(result>0)
    //{
    // TheStopLoss=0;
    // TheTakeProfit=0;
    // if(TakeProfit>0) TheTakeProfit=Ask+TakeProfit*MyPoint;
    // if(StopLoss>0) TheStopLoss=Ask-StopLoss*MyPoint;
    // OrderSelect(result,SELECT_BY_TICKET);
    // OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(TheStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(TheTakeProfit,Digits),0,Green);
    //}
    return(0);
 }
 if(
 (iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_SIGNAL,0)>iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_MAIN,0))&&
 (iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,1)>iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,0)) 
 ) // Here is your open Sell rule
 {
    result=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,Lots,Bid,Slippage,0,0,"EA Generator www.ForexEAdvisor.com",MagicNumber,0,Red);
    Alert("SELL OPENED");
    //if(result>0)
    //{
    // TheStopLoss=0;
    // TheTakeProfit=0;
    // if(TakeProfit>0) TheTakeProfit=Bid-TakeProfit*MyPoint;
    // if(StopLoss>0) TheStopLoss=Bid+StopLoss*MyPoint;
    // OrderSelect(result,SELECT_BY_TICKET);
    // OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(TheStopLoss,Digits),NormalizeDouble(TheTakeProfit,Digits),0,Green);
    //}
    return(0);
     }
  }

  for(int cnt=0;cnt<OrdersTotal();cnt++)
      {
      OrderSelect(cnt, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES);
   if(OrderType()<=OP_SELL &&   
     OrderSymbol()==Symbol() &&
     OrderMagicNumber()==MagicNumber 
     )  
    {
     if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)  
       {
          if(
          (iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_SIGNAL,0)>iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_MAIN,0))&&
          (iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,1)>iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,0))) //here is your close buy rule
          {
               OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderClosePrice(),Slippage,Red);
               Alert("BUY CLOSED");
          }
        if(TrailingStop>0)  
          {                 
           if(Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>MyPoint*TrailingStop)
             {
              if(OrderStopLoss()<Bid-MyPoint*TrailingStop)
                {
                 OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),Bid-TrailingStop*MyPoint,OrderTakeProfit(),0,Green);
                 return(0);
                }
             }
          }
       }
     else 
       {
            if(
            (iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_SIGNAL,0)<iStochastic(NULL,PERIOD_M15,5,3,3,MODE_EMA,1,MODE_MAIN,0))&&
            (iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,1)<iMACD(NULL,PERIOD_M15,12,26,1,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,0))) // here is your close sell rule
            {
               OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),OrderClosePrice(),Slippage,Red);
               Alert("SELL CLOSED");
            }
        if(TrailingStop>0)  
          {                 
           if((OrderOpenPrice()-Ask)>(MyPoint*TrailingStop))
             {
              if((OrderStopLoss()>(Ask+MyPoint*TrailingStop)) || (OrderStopLoss()==0))
                {
                 OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),Ask+MyPoint*TrailingStop,OrderTakeProfit(),0,Red);
                 return(0);
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
return(0);
}

int TotalOrdersCount()
{
  int result=0;
  for(int i=0;i<OrdersTotal();i++)
  {
     OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS ,MODE_TRADES);
     if (OrderMagicNumber()==MagicNumber) result++;

   }
  return (result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks whether there is at least one open deal, or not by using `TotalOrdersCount()` function. You need to remove that function, or hide it or edit in order to allow multiple trades. Currently the ea checks how much deals are opened by expert advisors with the same magic number (and probably different symbols) and checks the long/short rules only if number of open deals is zero: see line `if( TotalOrdersCount()==0 )`.

If you need to found the latest opened trade - update the `TotalOrdersCount`and have time either a global variable, or pass it by reference.

```
int totalOrdersCount(datetime &lastOpenTrade)
  {
   int result=0; datetime last=0;
   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
      if(!OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS))continue;
      if(OrderMagic()!=InpMagicNumber)continue;
      if(OrderSymbol()!=_Symbol)continue;
      result++;
      if(OrderOpenTime()>last)last=OrderOpenTime();
     }
   lastOpenTrade=last;
   return(result);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I commented out  `TotalOrdersCount()` but it seems to be taking several trades within a very short duration. I know this sounds like a new question, but how can I make sure it only takes one trade within my specified time interval `PERIOD_M15` when other conditions are met?

Comment: I found this, but I want to hard code it for a specific duration rather.   `Int BarsCount = 0;
 
int start()
{
 
  if (Bars>BarsCount)
  {
    // executed only once per bar goes here. 
    BarsCount = Bars;
  }
  return(0);
}`

Comment: yes, but keep in mind you will be able to open a trade on the first tick only. if the condition is not met at the first tick - the ea will sleep all the time before the next candle is born. I would rather suggest to check thhe number of open trades and `OrderOpenTime()` of the latest trade and make sure the latter belongs to the previous bar using 'iBarShift()' function.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds far better. Would you mind updating your solution to include this?

Comment: Since build 600 there's no optimization in splitting up your statements with `continue`. Expressions are exited as soon as any of the conditionals evaluate to false.